# Getting back names instead of ID for two columns in query from separate table

Tags: mysql, database

My current query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(emp.firstName, ' ', emp.lastName), gear.gearCata 
FROM gear_search as gear 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee as emp ON gear.PrimarySalesid = emp.salesid 
WHERE gear.CompanyName = 'rty';
```

What I want is the result to list the first and last name of primary and secondary sales persons instead of their ID's, and the secondary has to show an NULL of empty result so I can see where they line up.

```
So like this
PrimarySales Name | GearCatagory | Secondary Name
Bill Jones           Climbing         NULL
Terry Anderson       Running          Bill Jones

... and so on
```

Basically, **gear_search** table does not have sales peoples names just their primary and secondary sales ID's for each transaction. I have to use the employee table to get their actual names.

I know I could do this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(emp.firstName, ' ', emp.lastName), gear.gearCata, gear.SecondarySalesid
FROM gear_search as gear 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee as emp ON gear.PrimarySalesid = emp.salesid 
WHERE gear.CompanyName = 'rty';
```

But this would just show their Secondarysalesid not their name.

I have tried joining employee again on Secondarysalesid  and using CONCAT again, but it will not line up with the primary correctly. I need to see which deals only had a primary and then (primary and secondary)

Any advice would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join employee again:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CONCAT(emp.firstName, ' ', emp.lastName) PrimaryName,
  gear.gearCata,
  CONCAT(emp2.firstName, ' ', emp2.lastName) SecondaryName
FROM gear_search as gear
LEFT JOIN employee emp ON gear.PrimarySalesid = emp.salesid 
LEFT JOIN employee emp2 ON gear.SecondarySalesid = emp2.salesid 
WHERE gear.CompanyName = 'rty'
```

Comment: This actually did not work on our production DB, it returned 20,000 results when the gear_search table only has 160 rows and employee only has 320. Thanks for the help non the less...

Comment: @trail_runner try adding DISTINCT - see edited answer. Also, are you sure you copied the join conditions correctly? I recommend copy-paste, because if for example you mistype even one character incorrectly, like `emp` instead of `emp2`, you can get crazy results

Comment: Still not working? What's happening now? Maybe show some sample data so we've got something to code against.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you join "employee" to "gear_search" twice, something like this (excuse the old-school syntax not using LEFT JOIN, it's what I'm more familiar with:

SELECT CONCAT(emp1.firstName, ' ', emp1.lastName), 
gear.gearCata , 
CONCAT(emp2.firstName, ' ', emp2.lastName)
FROM gear_search as gear ,
     employee as emp1,
     employee as emp2
WHERE
gear.CompanyName = 'rty'
AND
 gear.PrimarySalesid = emp1.salesid 
 and
 gear.SecondarySalesid = emp2.salesid

although your post says that you tried something like this, it's not clear whether you had "employee" in the query twice.  So I may be telling you the time by your own watch here.

Comment: "old school"? Like when they used stone tablets and chisels? `JOIN` has been in the SQL language for over 20 years! Before many of the users here were born... Get with the program(ming)!

Comment: yup, those good old days before sql92.... actually my example code is incorrect because my joins are not outer joins.  The 'joining same table twice' trick is worth remembering.